# I got NaN for calculating the difference between dates

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to calculate the difference between a column and a specified date but the outpout is NaN.

```
'''
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m-%d-%YYYY', errors='coerce')
df['date']=df['date'].agg(pd.Timestamp)
df['Days']=df['date'].agg(lambda x:(today-x).days)
df['Days']
'''
```

0  NaN
.
.
.

Comment: Can you attach a sample df?

Comment: @Sala
a b date
1 56 10/3/2014
2 30 2015/02/29
3 20 2015/02/29
4 25 2015/02/29
5 11 2015/02/29

Comment: i found out that the output of first line is NaT. why? some of dates begin with year and some of them with day. can it be the reason? how can i fix it?